# Kubernetes Deployment RollingUpdate does not add new environment variable

Tags: kubernetes

Im on kubernetes 1.3.5, we are using Deployments with rollingupdates to update the pods in our cluster. However, on rollingupdate, the newly added environment variable never gets added to the pod, is it by design ? what are the ways to get around that ?

Following is the sample deployment yaml files. Basically the deployment was deployed with first version then we updated the yaml with newly added env variable `NEW_KEY` and basically run through the rolling updated. But the new env does not show up in the PODS.

first version yaml

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: APP_NAME-deployment
  labels:
    name: APP_NAME
    environment: DEV
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: APP_NAME
        environment: DEV
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: APP_NAME
          image: repo.app_name:latest
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: 'development'
            - name: APP_KEY
              value: '123'`

updated yaml

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: APP_NAME-deployment
  labels:
    name: APP_NAME
    environment: DEV
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: APP_NAME
        environment: DEV
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: APP_NAME
          image: repo.app_name:latest
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: 'development'
            - name: APP_KEY
              value: '123'
            - name: NEW_KEY
              value: 'new'`

Comment: are you defining the new env var inside your Dockerfile and/or from a -e parameter or ... ?

Comment: Yes cant really answer this without knowing how are you adding the env var. Also note that Pods wont be updated unless PodTemplateSpec changes in deployment

Comment: It would be useful if you give your deployment config, your kubectl command etc.

Comment: ok updated the post with a bit more detail, basically we add the new env variable to the deployment container spec.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the env variable in either a ConfigMap or secretKeyRef. For a ConfigMap you would do:

```
      env:
        - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: node_env
              key: node.dev
```

Or with a secretKeyRef:

```
      env:
        - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: node_env
              key: node.dev
```